# flutter - widget tests - why my line coverage not reflected for super constructor call?

Tags: flutter, code-coverage, flutter-test

I have few widgets under test and their super constructor doesn't gets called (some it works fine and for others it won't work as expected after many different tries)

line coverage - super(key: key) shows in RED for coverage.

Attaching few images for references..

> **Not working as expected**
>
> [image: UserAvatar] [image: AppCahcedNetworkImage]

--

> **Working as expected**
>
> [image: RoundIconButton] [image: AppFlare]

[image: Coverage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38934#issuecomment-803938315

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use
`// coverage:ignore-line`

Maybe you can try to use instead of this format:

```
const UserAvatar({
    Key? key,
    ...
}) : super(key:key);
```

You use this format:

```
const UserAvatar({
    super.key,
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea to try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's worked for me

Answer (score -1):

This is working as expected, but you can get around it with:

`// coverage:ignore-line`

Comment: adding ignore by hiding the warning is not a good idea